# How do you breed a Ruby Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I see the limited Gem dragon for the month of July is now available in the market. How do I breed a Ruby Dragon?  How will I know if I have one?

Comment: @Community you deleted part of the question when you edited, and the spelling was already correct. I rolled back, since I believe the "how do I know if I was successful" part of dragon breed questions is very interesting to breeders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dragonvale Wiki entry for Ruby Dragon:](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Ruby_Dragon)

> The Ruby Dragon can only be bred by selecting a Chrome Dragon to mate with a Scorch Dragon at the Breeding Cave/Epic Breeding Island.

Their breeding time is 31 hours

Answer (score -2):

Try copper or magnetic with blazing in EBI

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please avoid posting one line answer. Your answer lack any reference to back it up.

Answer (score -3):

Flower and bluefire. Try a few times.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please avoid posting one line answer. Your answer lack any reference to back it up.